# How to manage JavaScript events in application

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I will develop a medium-sized application which has client side JavaScript and ajax calls to server side (server can be vary of asp, PHP, node..).

I want to build everything on JavaScript events and manage these events in one js file because of to make it maintain easily.

I have started to bind all events on $ object which for call and bind js objects easily. Do you know any framework or tutorial to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of pub-sub / Event Emitter library. [Here's a 20-liner EventEmitter class called MicroEvent](http://notes.jetienne.com/2011/03/22/microeventjs.html) which you could use for starters. If you happen to use jQuery, it also has custom events management using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), which works the same way as any other Event Emitter library.

Comment: You are absoulutly right and I'm using on, off, trigger but I want to find a way manage these events in one file, class etc. Because every element will have event and submit. I don't want to use them in every '$(function(){})' .

Answer (score 0):

Probably are you looking for this:
http://millermedeiros.github.io/js-signals/